# Как зделать текст на кнопке

Tags: python, pygame

Не знаю как сделать текст на кнопке шоб при изменении кнопки текст тоже изменялся

[image: Меню]

тут код

````
    def __init__(self, screen, color, weight, height, x, y, action, message, font_name, color_text):
        self.scr = screen
        self.color = color
        self.color_text = color_text
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.action = action
        self.message = message
        self.font_name = font_name

    def update(self):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        font = pygame.font.Font(self.font_name, self.weight - 50)
        text_surface = font.render(self.message, True, self.color_text)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.midtop = (self.x + 15, self.y + 15)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.scr, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.weight, self.height))
        self.scr.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

        if self.x < mouse[0] < self.x + self.weight:
            if self.y < mouse[1] < self.y + self.height:
                if click[0] == 1:
                    self.action()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте реплизовать кнопку данным образом:

```
class BTN:
    def __init__(
        self,
        width,
        height,
        font=pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 35, bold=True),
        font_size=35,
        color=(31, 133, 222),
    ):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 30, bold=True)
        self.font_size = 35
        self.colorP = (31, 133, 222)
        self.color = (239, 239, 239)

    def draw(self, x, y, message, play=None):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if x < mouse[0] < x + self.width:
            if y < mouse[1] < y + self.height:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colorP, (x, y, self.width, self.height))

                if click[0] == 1:
                    print("Кнопка нажата!")

                    pygame.time.delay(300)
                    if play is not None:
                        play()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (x, y, self.width, self.height))

        print_text(message, x + 10, y + 10)

if __name__=="__main__":
    btn = btn(100, 100) # Размеры кнопки
    btn.draw(20, 100, "PLAY") # Кординаты кнопки(x, y), текст кнопки
```

Comment: Спасибо большое